# How to display some Ushahidi's layers (WFS) in my Web portal?

Tags: openlayers, wfs, ogc, ushahidi

I'm working on a VGI Web portal. I'm using OpenLayers and the application is running through the TomCat server. I would like to know if it's possible to display layers from Ushahidi or others VGI tools using OGC services (Web Feature Service).

If it is possible, how could I do it?

Comment: USHAHIDI does not have a WFS protocol

Answer (score 1):

there is no problem adding any public WFS to OpenLayers.

Here is another question that can help you [How to add a simple WFS layer from GeoServer to OpenLayers map?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19033/how-to-add-a-simple-wfs-layer-from-geoserver-to-openlayers-map).

I recommend you this two links:

- OpenLayers presentation: http://acanimal.github.com/OpenLayers-Presentation/
- OpenLayers Cookbook examples: http://acanimal.github.com/Openlayers-Cookbook/

The only issue you can have with WFS is requests are made using AJAX and you can have problems with XDR (cross domain requests. Because this you need a "proxy", that is, a script on your server that receives the request from the client side, make the real request and return the values to the client side.

Cheers.