# Openlayers: zoomToExtent from a polygon

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, zoom

I tried all the day to zoom by default on my polygon 'geofield'. I'm using geoserver to store my data, I can display the map but the centre is in the middle of nowhere (I want it to be in the middle of the geofield). I tried something like this:

`map.zoomToExtent(geofield.getDataExtent());`

but it doesn't work! I also tried with a button like this:

`var zoomToExtentControl = new ol.control.ZoomToExtent({
        extent: [-11243808.051695308, 4406397.202710291,-4561377.290892059,6852382.107835932]});`

it works when I clicked on it but when I try to replace the coordinates by `geofield.geometry.getBounds()` the map doesn't display.

Here you can see the full code:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.18.2/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
  <style>
    .map {
      height: 400px;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.18.2/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <title>OpenLayers 3 example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Weeds map test</h2>
  <div id="map" class="map"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
var zoomToExtentControl = new ol.control.ZoomToExtent({
        extent: geofield.geometry.getBounds());
      });

    var map = new ol.Map({
      target: 'map',
      layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        title: 'Global Imagery',
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
          url: 'http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms',
          params: {LAYERS: 'nasa:bluemarble', VERSION: '1.1.1'}
        })
      }),
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        title: 'geofield',
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
          url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/robot/wms',
          params: {LAYERS: 'robot:geofield', VERSION: '1.1.1'}
        })
      }),
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        title: 'weeds',
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
          url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/robot/wms',
          params: {LAYERS: 'robot:weeds', VERSION: '1.1.1'}
        })
      }),

      ],
      controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
        new ol.control.ScaleLine()]),
      view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
        zoom: 5
      })
    });

            map.addControl(zoomToExtentControl);

      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Another thing; if you have a wms link for the world map (not satellite view) I'll need it!

Comment: What is the output of `geofield.getDataExtent()` ? Are you using the right projection?

Comment: `ReferenceError: geofield is not defined` and the projection is EPSG:4326

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your layers as variables outside the map to make them accessible:

```
var geofield = new ol.layer.Tile({
  title: 'geofield',
  source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/robot/wms',
    params: {LAYERS: 'robot:geofield', VERSION: '1.1.1'}
  })
});
```

In your map definition use your layer variables:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [geofield, ...], // use your layers defined before...
  controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([new ol.control.ScaleLine()]),
    view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
      zoom: 5
  })
});
```

Then you can use `getExtent()` function on your layer (see [API](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.layer.Tile.html)). 
Note that your function `getDataExtent` does not exist...

**EDIT:** Use this function to zoom to your extent:

```
var zoomToGeofield = function(){
    var layerExtent = geofield.getExtent();
    map.getView().fit(layerExtent, map.getSize()); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I change those things and I let you know if ti's works :)

Comment: I tryed to pout the `map.zoomToExtent(geofield.getExtent());` at the end just before the `</script>` and the console sent me the error `TypeError: map.zoomToExtent is not a function` then I tried `console.log(geofield.getExtent());` just to see what output it is and I have an `undefined`

Comment: In OL3 you need to use view.fit instead of map.zoomToExtent - http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.View.html#fit

Comment: Thank you I used `zoomToGeofield` It's a big progress! But now I have a new error ´AssertionError: Assertion failed. See http://openlayers.org/en/v3.18.2/doc/errors/#24 for details.´ witch means `Invalid extent or geometry provided as geometry` I think it's a problem of reference

Comment: What is the result of `geofield.getExtent()`?

Comment: with `console.log(geofield.getExtent());` I have `undefined` and with just `geofield.getExtent();`  there is no error

Comment: Maybe I have to set a baseLayer

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea why the extent is undefined. Is your polygon static? Then you could create a polygon (`ol.geom.Polygon` ) and use the `getExtent() ` function (http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.geom.Polygon.html#getExtent). Or is your service available as WFS too (WFS example: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/examples/vector-wfs.html)? Then you might be able to use `getExtent() ` on `ol.source.vector` (http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html#getExtent)

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip, I didn't really get what does the doc says " method is not available when the source is configured with useSpatialIndex set to false." fot getExtent() 
My polygon isn't static so I can't fix solid values for the extent but I think there is a way to use a wfs via geoServer (my datas comes from postGis)

Comment: ok I found what I need [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19033/how-to-add-a-simple-wfs-layer-from-geoserver-to-openlayers-map)

Comment: I tried to get the geofield feature by loading it by geoJson via wfs request `var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
  url: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
    return 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/robot/ows?service=WFS' +
    '&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=robot:geofield&' +
    'outputFormat=application%2Fjson';
  },
  strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.tile(ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({
  }))
});`

But it doesn't work. I have the folloing error message

Comment: `Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing`