# How to make WFS layer with GeoExt?

Tags: geoserver, wfs, geoext

Can you help me with WFS on GeoExt? 
I'm read tutorial and see this code.

```
proxy: new GeoExt.data.ProtocolProxy({
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
            url: "/geoserver/ows",
            version: "1.1.0",
            featureType: "parks",
            featureNS: "http://medford.opengeo.org",
            srsName: "EPSG:4326"
        })
    })
```

After this I see this `var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Editable features");` And don't understand how to create a layer. So I have some questions.

1. How to get URL for the WFS? (I use GeoServer)
2. What does it mean by `featureType` option.
3. And more important. This code is correct? I find it here http://workshops.opengeo.org/geoext/wfs/grid.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would benefit from splitting your problem into GeoExt and OpenLayers.

Start with the OpenLayers examples (http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/), looking at each WFS example to see how it is done. Here is a really simple example http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/wfs-states.html - zoom in a bit if you don't see the white states outlines. Now look at the code for that (http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/wfs-states.js). Now work through the other WFS examples.

featureType is the name of the "layer" on the WFS server.

Edits:
http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#ProxyHost described why you might need a ProxyHost, and how to set it up.

The namespace qualifies the featureType, so a server can offer more than one WFS layer with the same name (e.g. "tanks" could mean something different in a military sense and in a water sense).

Comment: Thank u. I see this example. But i dont know wnat is it `OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "proxy.cgi?url=";`. Can u say me?  And `featureNS` thi is name of the workspace?

Comment: Try do like in this example but dont see a layer. In firebug i see answer from geoserver with layer but on map is nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You should check this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/12151/4461), regarding your confusions in the original question. And regarding OpenLayers.ProxyHost, you can check this [link](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#ProxyHost). There are several other related [questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wfs?sort=votes) here, you can read through them to have a better understanding.